# Class.getDeclaredMethods() of reflection peculiar behavior

Tags: java, reflection

I have a abstract class A, class B is concrete class that extends A.

Calling B.class.getDeclaredMethods() returns class A's method signatures in addition to class B's but JAVA documentation says some thing different on  `getDeclaredMethods()`

> *"This includes public, protected, default (package)
>   access, and private methods, but excludes inherited methods."*

So from above docs i was expecting method foo() which is inherited from abstract parent class should not be returned from `getDeclaredMethods()` call, but i am getting method foo() which is inherited from abstract parent class is returned from `getDeclaredMethods()` call.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class B extends A {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method[] methods = B.class.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(methods[i]);
        }
    }
}


abstract class A {
    public void foo() {
    }
}
```

Can some one explain me this behavior.

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce (only main is printed): http://ideone.com/lnh6HE

Comment: Please check the output attached

Comment: Interesting - it *is* printing `public void B.foo()` for me, unexpectedly.

Comment: @assylias is saying, its working fine  for him..(

Comment: Interestingly, `javap -c B` shows a `B.foo()` method basically calling `super.foo()`.

Comment: @assylias: Have you tried it locally? It's as if `B` is implicitly providing an implementation calling `super.foo()`.

Comment: @JonSkeet--Sir could you please explain why it is doing so and where i am mistaken

Comment: No, I can't - hence "unexpectedly". I don't understand it at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet actually I get a different output when B is a top level class (prints foo) and when it's a nested class (doesn't print foo).

Comment: @assylias: I've found some other aspects that are interesting, too.

Comment: @JonSkeet--Please share other aspects with us sir... :)

Comment: I notice that you will get the desired output if you make foo() final. This is definitely not the behavriour I expected

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason you get this is because the superclass has package level access.
If you change the access modifier of class `A` to `public` (you'll need to put it in its own file), the extra method in `B.class.getDeclaredMethods()` disappears.

(Also note that the `abstract` modified on class `A` is a red herring: the same thing occurs when class `A` is not abstract)

This is a workaround *in the Java compiler* for a bug in reflection: although `foo` is a public method, it was defined in package scoped class `A`. You could reflect on class `B`, find the method, try to invoke it using reflection, only to get an `IllegalAccessException`.

The compiler will generate a *bridge method* in class `B` so that you can correctly reflectively invoke method `foo`.

---

This is best demonstrated if you make the method `foo` in `A` a `final` method, which makes it impossible to fix this reflection bug (it's not possible to override the method)

Classes `A` and `B` are in package `abc` and class `C` is in package `def`. Class `C` tries to reflectively invoke method `foo` on class `B` which is public, but it fails because it was defined in non-public class `A`.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class
>   def.C can not access a member of class abc.A with modifiers "public
>   final"

```
package abc;

public class B extends A {
}

class A {
    public final void foo() {
    }

}
```

```
package def;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import abc.B;

public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method m = B.class.getMethod("foo");
        m.invoke(new B());
    }
}
```

Just removing the `final` keyword from method `foo` resolves the problem, because the compiler then inserts the synthetic bridge method in class `B`.

---

It's explained in this bug report:

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6342411

> ## Description
>
> The program below fails at runtime with this error:
>
> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class refl.ClientTest can not access a member of class refl.a.Base with
> modifiers "public"
>         at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:65)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
>         at refl.ClientTest.main(ClientTest.java:9)
> ```
>
> ```
> ========== test/refl/a/Base.java ========== 
>      1  package refl.a; 
>      2   
>      3  class Base { 
>      4      public void f() { 
>      5          System.out.println("Hello, world!"); 
>      6      } 
>      7  } 
> ========== test/refl/a/Pub.java ========== 
>      1  package refl.a; 
>      2   
>      3  public class Pub extends Base {} 
> ========== test/refl/ClientTest.java ========== 
>      1  package refl; 
>      2  import refl.a.*; 
>      3  import java.lang.reflect.*; 
>      4   
>      5  public class ClientTest { 
>      6      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
>      7          Pub p = new Pub(); 
>      8          Method m = Pub.class.getMethod("f"); 
>      9          m.invoke(p); 
>     10      } 
>     11  }
> ```

> ## EVALUATION
>
> The proposal is to add bridge methods in these very rare cases to fix
>   a problem in reflection with no other forseen fix or workaround. 
>   Specifically, we would generate a bridge method when a public method
>   is inherited from a nonpublic class into a public class.

Answer (score 13):

For the reasons listed by the other answers, sometimes the compiler have to add some tricky code to your class file; this can be in the form of fields, constructors or methods. However, it always mark those fields as `synthetic`. That's an actual modifier it adds, and you can check if the method is synthetic with the method:

```
method.isSynthetic()
```

So whenever you get all methods, filter your list with this method to select only the ones you actually declared in the source ;)

Other examples of synthetic code are: default constructors that get automatically added, a reference to the outer class in a field if you have a non-static inner-class.

Answer (score 1):

The oddity isn't in `getDeclaredMethods()` - it's in the class file for `B`, with a body that just calls `super.foo()`.

I don't *fully* understand it, but it appears to be related to `foo()` being a *public* method declared in a *package-private* superclass.

Some test cases:

- `A` package-private, `foo` public (as per question): method is generated in `B`
- `A` package-private, `foo` package-private: method isn't generated in `B`
- `A` public, `foo` public: method isn't generated in `B`
- `A` public, `foo` package-private: method isn't generated in `B`

I suspect the idea is that a third class in a different package can't "see" `A`, but `A.foo()` is still `public`, so it should (?) be accessible through `B`. In order to *make* it accessible, `B` needs to "redeclare" it.

It's not clear to me that this is actually correct - the (?) above. JLS 6.6.1 states (emphasis mine):

> A member (class, interface, field, or method) of a reference type, or a constructor of a class type, is accessible **only if the type is accessible** and the member or constructor is declared to permit access

But this code *is* allowed in a different package:

```
B b = new B();
b.foo();
```

Comment: what still confuses me: If you make foo() final, then it doesn't show in the list of declared Methods anymore. That would mean B doesn't need to re-declare it to make it publicly visible?

Comment: See my answer for the base explanation - it fully explains the problem including why the method in `B` disappears when you make the method in `A` a `final` method.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: Well discovered :) Will leave this answer for a bit more context.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you found [a bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6815786?jql=text%20~%20%22getDeclaredMethods%22) which hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: I don't think so. I believe it's accurately reflecting what's in the class file.

Comment: @JonSkeet The bug is still open and status is unresolved. May be still a bug ?

Comment: @JonSkeet The code in the bug report is *exactly* the same as the Op's code.

Comment: It's not a bug in `getDeclaredMethods` but in the basically a bug in how methods are modeled for the reflection API. The last comment on the above bug "Suspect bridge method is being added from implementing a public methods from a non-public class." is the reason that you see this extra method - see my answer for full details.

Comment: @assylias: I didn't make it as clear as I should have done - Erwin's comment is what I should have written :)